# Excel Range count and items size difference

Tags: excel, vba

I declare or select a Range on an Excel Worksheet. After it if i ask the size of it or try to manipulate an item, the item value can be greater than the actual Count value. This is the code for checking it.

```vba
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D4")
    Debug.Print x.Count
    Debug.Print x(x.Count)
    Debug.Print x(x.Count + 1)
```

This small snippet should give an error on the last line as i think because the index value is greater than the collection's elements count. In this case the cells number of the selection.
However the result is the underlying line's first cell's value and not an error message.
Isn't it a bug?

Comment: 'x' is a range not a collection so you can to use `x(n)` or `x.Cells(n)` to refer to cells outside the range of x like `.Offset(r,c)`. Try `For n = 1 To x.Count + 5: Debug.Print n, x(n).Address: Next`

Comment: @cdp1802 Yes this is my problem, because when i use it in a Selection which gives back a Range the Selection.Count value is correct, but after referring to a concrete cell of the selection like in the post it step through the limit. Generally cannot give higher value then a Something.Count value

Comment: That’s just how excel works.  The Count is correct, so use that to limit which cells you address within your selection.